# "else if" in janino logback configuration

Tags: conditional-statements, logback, janino

I am trying to use janino conditional statements in logback configuration and it is working fine with "if" and "else". But I want to ask if there is it possible to write "else if" in it?

My case -

```xml
<if condition='p("log.environment").equals("prod")'>
    <then>
        <include file="${LOG_CONFIG_DIR}/logback-prod.xml" />
    </then>
</if>

<if condition='p("log.environment").equals("uat")'>
    <then>
        <include file="${LOG_CONFIG_DIR}/logback-uat.xml" />
    </then>
</if>

<if condition='p("log.environment").equals("dev")'>
    <then>
        <include file="${LOG_CONFIG_DIR}/logback-dev.xml" />
    </then>
</if>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try to do like this.

```xml
<if condition=''>
  <then>..</then>
  <else>
    <if condition=''>
      <then>..</then>
      <else>..</else>
    </if>
  </else>
</if>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `if-then-else` in multi-level

```xml
<if condition='p("log.environment").equals("prod")'>
    <then>
        <include file="${LOG_CONFIG_DIR}/logback-prod.xml" />
    </then>
    <if condition='p("log.environment").equals("uat")'>
       <then>
            <include file="${LOG_CONFIG_DIR}/logback-uat.xml" />
       </then>
       <else>
           <include file="${LOG_CONFIG_DIR}/logback-dev.xml" />
       </else>
    </if>
</if>
```